# PHP file load time, perhaps related to NFS?

Tags: nfs, php

### The Problem

I'm attempting to diagnose a performance issue on a Drupal website I'm developing.
In the morning, when the site has seen no traffic (not even a cron run) for over 8 hours, the homepage takes around 3.5 seconds to load. Reloading the page takes an expected 250ms.

This is a development web server, with a fairly old version of PHP installed (5.3.3). *All of the files are statically mounted over NFS* (which I believe is the root cause, more on that below).

To help diagnose, I installed [XHProf](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) on this development server, and enabled a Drupal module that profiles page loads and displays the profiling data in a nicely sortable table. For those unfamiliar with XHProf, it provides data on every function called and things like the total time spent, memory usage, and calls for that function.

### My Findings

On the initial "slow" hit, the PHP function `file_exists` took **1400ms** from 82 calls, accounting for roughly 43% of the total execution time. On the subsequent page load, the same function `file_exists` was again called 82 times, but this time it was dramatically reduced to just **3ms** accounting for just 1% of the total execution time.

I additionally looked at the file that took the longest for PHP to load into memory (which is what I believe the `load::` prefix means on a function name). This PHP template file took a whopping **42ms** to load the first time around, and only **3ms** on the subsequent reload!

### What I suspect

It's clear to me there is some sort of caching going on somewhere - I just don't know where yet. The PHP docs for [file_exists](https://www.php.net/file_exists) mention that the output of this function is cached. I then found I can [control the size of this cache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath-cache-size.php) and it should probably be increased from the default 16k to something more appropriate for Drupal (which loads tons of relative files).

However, while I think that would reduce the amount of time spent in `file_exists`, I'm not sure that will affect the time PHP takes actually *loading* the file (the `load::` I mentioned earlier) and increasing this value seems to just be hiding underlying performance issues with the file system.

### Questions

1. If there are any XHProf or PHP veterans that can confirm if the increasing PHP's `realpath_cache` had any impact on the time reported in `load::` from XHProf?
2. What underlying caching mechanisms should I be aware of in Linux that could have an impact?
3. Same as above, but for NFS?

Comment: Which version of NFS?  TCP, UDP?

Comment: Drupal has a cron built in for cache refresh that causes this (from my experience working with a few Drupal builds), this article has good information:http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-drupals-cron-killing-you-your-sleep-simple-cache-warmer

Comment: @Schrute, this is unrelated to Cron, I have Drupal 7's built in "poor mans cron" disabled

Comment: @Steve-o, I'm honestly not sure?